# Unhandled error Network error: Network request failed Error: Network request failed Error: at new ApolloError

Tags: android, react-native, apollo-client

> I  got this error in my application ( react-native ) when internet connection is lost.
>   When i start the app on offline mode, Initial component renders, try to execute the query, app crashes.
>   it works perfect when my app is connected with internet. But my application crashes when its not. How can i handle this error?

***ExceptionsManager.js:71 "Unhandled error Network error: Network request failed Error: Network error: Network request failed at new ApolloError"***

```
import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import {SubscriptionClient, addGraphQLSubscriptions} from 'subscriptions-transport-ws';

const wsClient = new SubscriptionClient('wss://172.20.32.6:5000', {
  reconnect: true,
  connectionParams: {
    accessToken: 'jka sdhkjashd jkashdjk ashdas'
  }
});

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
   uri: 'http://172.20.32.6:8000/graphql',
   opts: {
    credentials: 'same-origin'
    }
});
const networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions = addGraphQLSubscriptions(
  networkInterface,
  wsClient
);
const client = new ApolloClient({
  dataIdFromObject: o => o.id,
  networkInterface: networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions

});
networkInterface.use([{
  applyMiddleware(req, next) {
    if (!req.options.headers) {
      req.options.headers = {};  // Create the header object if needed.
    }
    // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
    AsyncStorage.getItem('sessionToken').then((token) => {
      req.options.headers.Authorization = token ? `${token}` : null;
      next();
    }
    );
  }
}]);
export default client;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this very unhelpful error, add something like this at the top of the component that renders your query result.

```
if (data && data.error) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(data.error)}</Text>
      </View>
    )
}
```

more info of dealing with error can be found in this github issue
https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/604